# Is the $p$-norm ever a norm for $0<p<1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

I wonder:

Is there a measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ such that $L^p(\mu)$ form a normed space w.r.t the $p$-norm, for some $0<p<1$?(assuming that $X$ contains more than point).

I know that in general the "$p$-norm" is not really a norm for $0<p<1$. 
(it violates the triangle inequality). I am asking if there are (non-trivial) special cases where it *does* form a norm.

Comment: I suppose you also assume that $\mu$ is non-atomic (otherwise it is the same as $X$ is just a point).

Comment: If there exists measurable $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ such that $\mu(\mathcal{A}),\mu(\mathcal{B})>0$ but $\mu(\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B})=0$ then you can take $f=1_A,g=1_B$ as a counter-example for the triangle inequality.

Comment: We know that the metric $d(f,g)=\int \vert f-g \vert ^p d\mu$ forms a TVS (even an F-space/Frechet space) on $L^p(\mu)$, so you can ask a more general question of whether this space is normable by some norm,. If the $p$ norm is a norm, it immediately gives the topology defined by $d$. You could ask whether $L^p$ is locally convex.

Comment: @Yano Thanks. Do you think that any measure space which does not satisfy your assumptions is atomic? (i.e. the measure is supported on a single point?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this question, I am expanding Yanko's comment into an answer:

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose that there exist
measurable sets $A,B$ such that $\mu(A),\mu(B)>0$ but $\mu(A\cap B)=0$.
Set $f=1_A,g=1_B$.

Then, $\|f+g\|_p^p=\int_X (1_A+1_B)^p=\int_{A \cup B} (1_A+1_B)^p=\int_{A\setminus B} (1_A+1_B)^p+\int_{B\setminus A}(1_A+1_B)^p=$
$\int_{A\setminus B} 1_A+\int_{B\setminus A}1_B=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$,and $\|f\|_p=(\mu(A))^{\frac{1}{p}},\|g\|_p=(\mu(B))^{\frac{1}{p}}$.

Thus $$ \|f+g\|_p \le \|g\|_p+\|g\|_p \iff (\mu(A)+\mu(B))^{\frac{1}{p}} \le (\mu(A))^{\frac{1}{p}}+(\mu(B))^{\frac{1}{p}}$$.

When $0<p<1$, we have  $r=\frac{1}{p}>1$, and $(x+y)^r>x^r+y^r$, so the triangle inequality does not hold. Indeed, we can write

$$ (x+y)^r=(x+y)(x+y)^{r-1}=x(x+y)^{r-1}+y(x+y)^{r-1}>xx^{r-1}+yy^{r-1}=x^r+y^r,$$ where in the strict inequality step we have used the fact 
$ (x+y)^{r-1}>\max\{x^{r-1},y^{r-1}\}$, i.e. the fact that the function $x \to x^s$ is strictly increasing for $s>0$.